# Ethereum ERC20 token transaction between private(Hyperledger Fabric) and public(Ethereum) blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, erc20

I've developed a case study based on Hyperledger Fabric using the [fabric-chaincode-evm](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-evm) in order to develop Solidity smart contract.

Using chaincode-evm there's the Fab3 proxy in the middle between Application and Fabric Network that map the *Fabric User* with an *ethereum address* generated on the fly.

1. There's a way to run transaction of an ERC20 token over a public Blockchain(Ethereum) starting from my private fabric chaincode(smart contract) ?
2. There's some way to change the eth address generated by Fab3 proxy with my own eth address, or linking Metamask for example.

Comment: It's also my question. Could you find any solution for it?

Comment: I developed my own custom solution. I stored the mapping between the generated address and the Metamask address then I developed the endpoints that I need to split the flow and forward the requests to both the networks synchronizing the responses.